# how to access json data mule esb

Tags: json, esb, mule

i want to access json data generated from the sync flow into an async flow.
I am getting json data from sync flow correctly and i want to fetch certain attribute value from that my json data is as follows :

```
{"data" : [{"in_timestamp":"2012-12-04","message":"hello","out_timestamp":null,"from_user":"user2","ID":43,"to_user":"user1"}]} and to user is #[json:to_user]}
```

I want to access to_user attribute from this json format.
I have tried using `#[json:to_user]` but it simply prints it as a string and doesnt return any value.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The right expression based on your sample JSON is:

```
#[json:data[0]/to_user]
```

Comment: Thanks doc. Reference : https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/json-module-reference

Answer (score 3):

JsonPath expression are depreciated for now and you will even not get enough document on it for doing ..
So, currently you need to use either :- `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />`
or `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object" />`
or even `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to Object" />` to extract data from JSON depending on the JSON data

Comment: can you give MuleSoft reference docs where it says, jsonpath expression deprecated?. I believe only expression resolver is deprecated.

Comment: I have found a forum post, where  mariano.gonzalez has explained the situation.

"We have not deprecated expressions such as #[json:data/field]. What we have deprecated is the expression resolver mechanism that powers that expression. For some expression resolvers  . . . You can use it safely since we'll keep maintaining it until Mule 4."

See: https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/26717/correct-way-of-accessing-json-payload-in-mule-37.html