# Use value in JSON response as path in HTTP call in Mule

Tags: json, http, mule, httprequest

I'm looking at designing a dept sales workflow which can loop through the list of depts returned in the JSON response from a HTTP call and call the sales REST API for each dept id in the list.

Is this possible?

I'm struggling to see if it is possible to get each dept id out of the JSON to use in the path parameter in the HTTP call.

Comment: Can you post the flow that you are trying to use. It is possible using for each and before you do that you need to take the ID from the JSON message. Please post the message to give a solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach  where you can extract each dept id from json and call accordingly with deptId in RESTAPI. For each link reference.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/foreach

Comment: In the for each loop how can I reference the dept id field so I can use it in the http call?

Comment: You  need to extract the deptId from Json insidefor each and store it in flowVariable and you can use it in HTTP call dynamically. See How to extract from Json via MEL in this url might helps https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-expression-language-tips

Comment: Extract data from Json : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703573/how-to-access-json-data-mule-esb

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the each json dept list either by using the foreach scope or can you the Mule expressions: look at this site [link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/json-module-reference)